# Windows 10 Update Anniversary

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have installed Windows 10 on my Mac with BootCamp. This week, Anniversary Update has been released. I wanted to install it. I have launch wizard to upgrade Windows.

Windows restarts.

Now, even if I press 'Alt' key, the boot menu does not show. Mac OS X starts, slowly... very slowly... very very slowly... When login screen shows up, I can not use keyboard or trackpad.

To start my computer, I need to plug external keyboard and external mouse... Mac OS X is very slow (when I mouse the mouse, I need to wait few minutes before see the cursor movement)

Mac OS X started and logged in, I can use Mac correctly.

I can access to BOOTCAMP partition in Finder.
In Boot Camp Assistant, I can not see Windows Partition, whereas in Disk Utility, I can...

[image]

How can I start again on Windows without having to reinstall everything?

Comment: I have not tried the Wizard on a Mac machine yet. I did on a HP machine. The process is similar to a complete operating system upgrade. My fear is that you did not entirely complete this grade. I also wonder if any partitioning changes were made. What is the model and year of your Mac? Does Windows appear as a Startup Disk in the System Preferences? You can also post the output from the following commands.  (Although at this early stage I am not sure doing so will help) `diskutil list`, `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`. These commands will not change your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [Boot Camp: Set the default operating system](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17862?locale=en_US)

> After installing Windows, you can set the default operating system.
>   
>   
>   **Set the default operating system in OS X**
>
> 1. In OS X, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Startup Disk.
> 2. Select the startup disk with the default operating system you want to use.
> 3. If you want to start up using the default operating system now, click Restart.
>
> **Set the default operating system in Windows**
>
> You can’t change your startup volume to an external FireWire or USB
>   drive while you're using Windows.
>
> 1. In Windows 7, click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, then choose Boot Camp Control Panel.
>      In Windows 8, move the cursor to the upper-right or lower-right corner of the screen, then click Search. Search for “Boot Camp,” click
>      Settings, then click Boot Camp.
> 2. If a User Account Control dialog appears, click Yes.
> 3. Select the startup disk with the default operating system you want to use.
> 4. If you want to start up using the default operating system now, click
>      Restart. Otherwise, click OK.
>
> **Restart in OS X using the Boot Camp icon in the system tray**
>
> In Windows, click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, then choose
>   Restart in OS X. This also sets the default operating system to OS X.
>
> If you don’t see the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, click the
>   triangle to show hidden icons.